# How to implement iOS 11's MKUserTrackingButton

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios11, swift4

I'm trying to implement a MKUserTrackingButton (which is new in iOS 11 SDK). This "button" actually inherits from UIView so I just put a UIView instance on my Map and in the Identity Inspector, linked it to the MKUserTrackingButton class, added an outlet in my code and in viewDidLoad().

I initialize it the following way:

```
self.centerMapButton = MKUserTrackingButton.init(mapView: self.mapView)
```

However, nothing works, I just have a blank view on my Map.

PS: Here's the WWDC 2017 session about this new feature (at 1:25): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/

Here's the method I call in viewDidLoad() to implement the button:

```
func setupUserTrackingButtonAndScaleView() {
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    let button = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: mapView)
    button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8).cgColor
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(button)

    let scale = MKScaleView(mapView: mapView)
    scale.legendAlignment = .trailing
    scale.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scale)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 scale.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 scale.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor)])
}
```

Note that I have a mapView instance in my ViewController, of course.

Comment: Have you checked the [MapKit sample](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/MapKit-Sample.zip) linked in the page you specified. Find how `MKUserTrackingButton` is used in the sample code.

Comment: Yeah, I did use the method Apple uses, but nothing shows up... It must be something really stupid but I'm very confused...

Comment: You are showing only one line of your code, no one would be able to help you without showing more code. Count how may lines there are in the sample code of Apple's.

Comment: I edited my message to show you the code.

Comment: With your code shown, I can find an `MKUserTrackingButton` at the right-bottom corner of the main view. By the way, are you trying to show an `MKUserTrackingButton` by code or by IB?

Comment: The code above is the code Apple provides. Their app's main view is a full-screen map. In my app, the screen is split in two parts: the top part is a map and the bottom part is a list. In order to reuse their code, I changed the lines  `view.addSubview(button)` and `view.addSubview(scale)` to respectively `mapView.addSubview(button)` and `mapView.addSubview(scale)`, which makes sense so I expect to see the two items in the bottom right corner of the map.

Comment: As mentionned previously, I tried to implement the button (view actually) by IB - it didn't work - so I deleted the view I added by IB and got the code from Apple.

Comment: Please, an answer ?

Comment: What you are saying is so confusing, you say you instantiate the `MKUserTrackingButton` with IB but you also instantiate an `MKUserTrackingButton` with code. I have advised you to show more of  _**your**_ code but you have shown us Apple's code. I do not understand what you really want to do. If you really want to get an answer you should brush up your question with enough info which can reproduce your issue. Try to write a better question to get a better answer sooner.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your code against my MapKit app and it worked fine. Make sure you are passing the proper mapView instance to the MKUserTrackingButton.