# MKUserTrackingButton responds only on long press

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct StaticMapView: UIViewRepresentable{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .none
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
        mapView.showsScale = false
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.showsCompass = false
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: false)
        
        let centerButton = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: mapView)
        mapView.addSubview(centerButton)
        
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: StaticMapView
        
        init(_ parent: StaticMapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}

struct StaticMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StaticMapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D())
    }
}
```

I am trying to put a `MKUserTrackingButton` into a mapView. The button appears correctly but it doesn't respond to touches. It will only do the job after a long press. I would expect the button to respond on a tap and not just on a long press. Am I doing something wrong or is this expected?

Comment: You don't add the `MKUserTrackingButton` to the `MKMapView` - You should add it to the map's parent `UIView` and constrain its location so that it appears at the right position relative to the mapview.  You will need to refactor your struct so that it uses a `UIView` containing the mapview and the button rather than the mapview directly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766615/how-to-implement-ios-11s-mkusertrackingbutton

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference. I can see the button getting clicked but the action is triggered only after a long press (same as before)